# TRISA isn't set as an Input

Tags: assembly, mplab

I need to put PORTA as an Input, and PORTB as an Output, but for some reason, it isn't work with PORTA.

```
STATUS  EQU 03H
PORTA   EQU 05H
PORTB   EQU 06H
TRISA   EQU 85H
TRISB   EQU 86H
ADCON1  EQU 9FH

    ORG 00H         
    
    MOVLW   07H
    MOVWF   ADCON1
    
INICIO
    BSF STATUS, 5       
    MOVLW   B'11111111'     
    MOVWF   TRISA           
    MOVLW   B'00000000'     
    MOVWF   TRISB           
    BCF STATUS, 5   
    
BUCLE
    BTFSS       PORTA, 0        
        GOTO    ZEROVALUE       
    MOVLW       B'11111111'
    MOVWF       PORTB
        GOTO    BUCLE
 
 ZEROVALUE
    MOVLW       B'11110000'
    MOVWF       PORTB
        GOTO    BUCLE   
        
 END
```

As you can notice, the consequence is that in BUCLE, PORTA always will be 0, NO MATTER THE VALUE I PUT ON RA0.  However, I don't think the value of TRISA on my Watchers is correct, it sets TRISA value as it follows:

`TRISA 00011111`

Somebody knows WTF is happening?

Comment: Specify the PIC model please e.g. PIC16F877

Comment: Sure! It is a PIC16F877A

Answer (score 0):

**Proper BANK selection** is a big concern when it comes to PIC assembly. In order to get desired results you should know what BANK you're in at specific point of code. Your problem seems to arising because of inapropriate BANK selection when you're writing the `ADCON1` register which resides in **BANK 1** as do the `TRIS` registers.
Another issue I noted in your code is regarding BANK selection. It may seem sufficient to set only `RP0` bit when you switch between BANK0 and BANK1. But in fact you must ensure that `RP1` is set to zero before. If not done, you may actually switch between BANK2 and BANK3 which will left you with undesired results.
So the fixed code would be something like the following for proper port IO initialization:

```
    ORG 0

INICIO
    BCF     STATUS, 6 ; Make sure high bank control bit is off
    BCF     STATUS, 5 ; Make sure you're in BANK0
    ; Clear the port latches from junk values.
    CLRF    PORTA
    CLRF    PORTB
    ; Now configure control registers in BANK1 to make the ports digital IO
    ; and set as input or output as needed
    BSF     STATUS, 5 ; Switch to BANK1, here we know that RP1 bit is off
    ; You know the rest...
    MOVLW   07H
    MOVWF   ADCON1
    MOVLW   B'11111111'     
    MOVWF   TRISA           
    MOVLW   B'00000000'     
    MOVWF   TRISB           
    BCF     STATUS, 5
```

Please go ahead and try with this way and let me know the result.